# Instrumental variables and mixed/multilevel models

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, random-effects-model, instrumental-variables, growth-model

I want to estimate a growth model to model the growth trajectories of individuals $j$ over multiple time points $t$ by applying a standard mixed/mutilevel model (also known as  random coefficient model):

\begin{align}
Y_{tj} &= \beta_{0_j} + \beta_{1_j}A_{tj} + \beta_{2_j}X_{tj} + \beta_{3_j}Z_{tj} + e_{tj}  \\
\beta_{0_j} &= \beta_0 + u_{0_j}  \\
\beta_{1_j} &= \beta_1 + u_{1_j}  \\
\beta_{2_j} &= \beta_2 + u_{2_j}  \\
\beta_{3_j} &= \beta_3 + u_{3_j}
\end{align}

$A_{tj}$ is a linear growth function (i.e., time point of observation: $1,2,3, ..., t$). $X_{tj}$ is an exogenous covariate. $Z_{tj}$ is an endogenous covariate.  Let's further assume that I have reasons to believe that one of the independent variables on level 1, $Z_{ij}$, is endogenous.

I am wondering whether or not I can use an instrumental variable approach (using the lag of the endogenous variable as an instrument) to deal with the endogeneity of $Z_{ij}$. However, I have not found any references or examples. Is this  generally possible, and how can I change the standard R code for mixed models to do this? Currently I'm using the function call `lmer(Y ~ X + Z + (1 + X + Z | ID), data=data)`.

Gelman & Hill (2006), Chapter 23.4 ([pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/chap23.pdf)) show how to do this by applying a Bayesian approach. I would be interested in references and R code implementing a frequentist approach to control for endogeneity by using instrumental variables (i.e., lags of endogenous variables as instruments) within a multilevel model.

Comment: I have formatted your question with $L_AT^EX$. Please double-check that I haven't mistakenly introduced errors to your formulae.

Comment: I haven't worked with endogenous/exogenous variables. Having said that: Have you thought of using `lme` instead of `lmer` so that you can define an AR=1 correlation structure for your errors and see if that takes care of your endogeneity?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In fact I am doing this, but I did not want to complicate things. Unfortunately, this does not solve the endogeneity issue. Here is a paper illustrating why lagging variables does not help too much: http://www.business.otago.ac.nz/econ/seminars/Abstracts/2013/Reed20Sept_Doc1.pdf

Comment: Are there any updates to this problem? A frequentist approach in R would be great.

Comment: @ sam: Me and my colleagues started working on a R package which implements some approaches. An early version can be found at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/REndo/index.html.

Answer (score 3):

The paper of Peter Ebbes et al. (2005) proposes a Latent IV estimation, where you do not need external IVs.

- Ebbes, Peter; Wedel, Michel; Böckenholt, Ulf; Steerneman, Ton; (2005). "Solving and Testing for Regressor-Error (in)Dependence When no Instrumental Variables are Available: With New Evidence for the Effect of Education on Income." *Quantitative Marketing and Economics* 3(4): 365-392. http://hdl.handle.net/2027.42/47579

Also the paper by Kim and Frees 2007 proposes a GMM estimation that helps you address the endogeneity problems in MLM.

- Jee-Seon Kim, & Edward W. Frees (2007). "[Multilevel Modelling with Correlated Effects](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11336-007-9008-1#)". *Psychometrika*, 72, 4, pp. 505-533.

However, I have not seen any R code for any of the two approaches :(.